# snoflake: how to mention date type where data can be input in various formats

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a table

```
create or replace table "test" (
      type1 DATE,
      type2 DATE,
      type3 DATE
    );


insert into "test" (type1, type2, type3) values
   ('20170415', '1996','15042017');
   
select * from "test";
```

I dont see the results as intended, we can see the below image

[image]

How to get the results as i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are held in the underlying database as decimals, how they are displayed in the UI is determined by the account or session settings. If you want a date to be shown in a different format then you would need to convert it to a char in your SQL and supply the required format string.

If you insert a string into a date field then Snowflake will do its best to understand what date that string represents and convert it to that date - however you should always provide these strings in a date format that Snowflake is guaranteed to convert to the correct date or, preferably, explicitly cast the strings as dates. Don’t rely on Snowflake converting the dates in the way you require.

1996 is not a valid date so you can’t hold this value in a date column

Comment: whats the right format which snowflakes understands when inserted into the date field

Comment: It’s all documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#how-snowflake-determines-the-input-and-output-formats-to-use